# Infer (templ types within object

Tags: typescript

I am using [typebox](https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typebox) for generating types and schemas for a REST-API. I would like to organize REST-resources like this:

```
{
  querySchema: TSchema;
  responseSchema: TSchema;
  get: (query : QueryType) => ResponseType;
}
```

Where `QueryType = Static<typeof querySchema>` etc.

Right now, I have a Type that takes `typeof querySchema` as template arguments:

```
type Resource<Q extends TSchema, R extends TSchema> = 
{
  querySchema: Q;
  responseSchema: R;
  get: (query: Satic<Q>) => Static<R>
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having to use template types? I would like to have something like this:

```
type Resource = 
{
  querySchema: infer Q; // <-- infer Q from querySchema
  responseSchema: infer R;
  get: (query: Satic<Q>) => Static<R>
}
```

I have tried using a function as a "wrapper" around the type with no success:

```
const resource = <T>(
  r : T extends Resource<infer Q, infer R> ?
    Resource<Q, R> : 
    never,
) => r;

resource({ querySchema, responseSchema, ... }) // querySchema is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Is there a way to automatically infer the template arguments in Typescript?

Edit:

The behavior I am looking for is to be able to do this:

```
const users = resource(
    {
        // querySchema from typebox
        querySchema: Type.Object(...),

        /* this is where I would like TS to understand that q is of
         * type Static<typeof querySchema>
         * 
         */
        get: (q) => { ... } 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with the wrapper function, no need to have a conditional type. TypeScript will first infer from the type of the parameters and checks if it matches the generic, so this is how we will infer our `Q` and `R`

EDIT 3/24/2022 - This actually works now.

```js
const resource = <Q extends TSchema, R extends TSchema>(r: {
  querySchema: Q
  responseSchema: R
  get: (query: Static<Q>) => Static<R>;
}) => r;

resource({ querySchema, responseSchema, get })
```

This will now infer based on the value of querySchema/responseSchema

Comment: Thanks for the playground! Sadly, it seems to stop working once ```Static<T>``` depends on T (which it obviously does in reality). Do you know why that is?

Comment: @l'arbre Do you mean have the `get` key/value inferred from `querySchema` and `responseSchema`? In order to do that you'll have to move the get type definition to outside of Resource and into the resource wrapper function. I have attached a new playground link demoing this.

Comment: No, not exactly. I would like to define get: () => ... within the object so that I can construct a rest resource in one go with type safety and autocomplete in my IDE.

Comment: @l'arbre I have appended a new playground link, you can't have reverse inferences, but since TypeBox handily exports most of its types, we can piggyback off that to write our own type inference system.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate example but I think I may not have explained my issue well enough. I will add an edit to the question due to space limitations.

Comment: OK, I got it now. My best guess is that the inferencing fails once you start to go across multiple layers. But I have edited and posted a fix, that I have tested locally with the actual TypeBox definitions and seems good.

Comment: YES! This worked. Could not be simpler.